# Repeatedly extracting structured data between two words

Tags: python, awk

The input is defined like this:

```
SEQUENCE
ATTCGGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTA
423575
user_name
029708252
END
SEQUENCE
GCAAGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTGA
423600
user_name2
03276541
SEQUENCE
GTAAGATCTAATGACGGACGCTCCA
423625
user_name3
00923408271
END
SEQUENCE
GGCTATTAAGGGGTCGGACGCTCGC
423650
user_name4
00923408271
SEQUENCE
GTAACTAAACTTTAACGGACGCTCC
423675
user_name5
0653053443
END
SEQUENCE
```

The data has structure as:

```
SEQUENCE
string1
number1
string2
number2
END
SEQUENCE
```

Or:

```
SEQUENCE
string1
number1
string2
number2
SEQUENCE
```

Sometimes, an `END` is present before the `SEQUENCE` text.

---

I have several thousands of such blocks for analysis. Could we extract the data in the block to txt file as following,

```
ATTCGGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTA   423575  user_name   029708252
GCAAGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTGA   423600  user_name2  03276541
GTAAGATCTAATGACGGACGCTCCA   423625  user_name3  00923408271
GGCTATTAAGGGGTCGGACGCTCGC   423650  user_name4  00923408271
GTAACTAAACTTTAACGGACGCTCC   423675  user_name5  0653053443
```

With each line having data from one of the data blocks.
I am trying `sed` for looping over all blocks but I get only the alternating matches as a result. (`sed -n -e '/SEQUENCE/,/SEQUENCE/ p' input`)

(Open to exploring other languages for this, for example, say python.)

Comment: The input is in what format? text file with new lines (Sequence, String1 , number1 ...)?

Comment: @Akshay  txt file with new lines.

Comment: @ankit7540, sorry but your sample expected output is not clear, kindly do add it more clearly and let us know then.

Comment: Are there always exactly two strings and numbers or may there be more or less?

Comment: I will update the exact output required in the post. There are always two strings and two numbers.

Comment: is before your number always the required string. if it is I think you could easily parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use python's `re` module for that following way:

```
import re
data = '''SEQUENCE
ATTCGGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTA
423575
user_name
029708252
END
SEQUENCE
GCAAGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTGA
423600
user_name2
03276541
SEQUENCE
GTAAGATCTAATGACGGACGCTCCA
423625
user_name3
00923408271
END
SEQUENCE
GGCTATTAAGGGGTCGGACGCTCGC
423650
user_name4
00923408271
SEQUENCE
GTAACTAAACTTTAACGGACGCTCC
423675
user_name5
0653053443
END
SEQUENCE'''

for record in re.findall(r'SEQUENCE\n(.+)\n(.+)\n(.+)\n(.+)', data):
    print(*record, sep='\t')
```

Output:

```
ATTCGGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTA       423575  user_name       029708252
GCAAGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTGA       423600  user_name2      03276541
GTAAGATCTAATGACGGACGCTCCA       423625  user_name3      00923408271
GGCTATTAAGGGGTCGGACGCTCGC       423650  user_name4      00923408271
GTAACTAAACTTTAACGGACGCTCC       423675  user_name5      0653053443
```

Explanation: I use pattern with capturing groups, by default `.` in python re denotes anything except newline, so I am capturing every four lines after `SEQUENCE`. When such pattern is used in `re.findall` it gives list of 4-tuple, so I unpack (using `*`) them and inform `print` to use `\t` as separator.

Comment: If I am correct, I can use `with open ("input.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()` to assign the content of file to python variable.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS="SEQUENCE\n" -v FS="\n|END" '{$1=$1} NF>1{sub(/ +$/,"");print}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v RS="SEQUENCE\n" -v FS="\n|END" '   ##Starting awk program from here, setting record separator as SEQUENCE new line and setting field separator as newline or END keyword here for all lines.
{
  $1=$1                                   ##Resetting 1st field here for all lines so that new values of RS, FS and OFS applied on it.
}
NF>1{                                     ##Checking if number of fields is greater than 1 here.
  sub(/ +$/,"")                           ##Substituting space at last of line with NULL here.
  print                                   ##Printing current line here.
}
' Input_file                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple way to read, process and write it as a text file -

```
filename = 'sample.txt'
outfile = 'processed_sample.txt'

with open(filename) as f:    
    content = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()] #read as a list and strip \n
    content = [i for i in content if i != 'END' and i != 'SEQUENCE'] #remove sequence and end tokens
    content = [' '.join(content[i:i + 4]) for i in range(0, len(content), 4)]  #break into parts of 4
    
content
```

This will get you a list like the following -

```
['ATTCGGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTA 423575 user_name 029708252',
 'GCAAGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTGA 423600 user_name2 03276541',
 'GTAAGATCTAATGACGGACGCTCCA 423625 user_name3 00923408271',
 'GGCTATTAAGGGGTCGGACGCTCGC 423650 user_name4 00923408271',
 'GTAACTAAACTTTAACGGACGCTCC 423675 user_name5 0653053443']
```

Next, you can write it to another text file as -

```
with open(outfile, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(content))
```

```
#Inside the text file
ATTCGGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTA 423575 user_name 029708252
GCAAGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTGA 423600 user_name2 03276541
GTAAGATCTAATGACGGACGCTCCA 423625 user_name3 00923408271
GGCTATTAAGGGGTCGGACGCTCGC 423650 user_name4 00923408271
GTAACTAAACTTTAACGGACGCTCC 423675 user_name5 0653053443
```

Answer (score 2):

I would first read the parts between "SEQUENCE" and "END" and store them. Then, feed them into a dataframe.

```
out = []
curr = []
lines = f.split('\n')
for l in lines:
    if "SEQ" in l or "END" in l:
        if len(curr)>0:
            out.append(curr)
            curr=[]
    else:
        try:
            curr.append(int(l))
        except:
            curr.append(l)

data = {"string1":[],"number1":[],"string2":[],"number2":[]}
for case in out:
    if len(case)==4:
        data["string1"].append(case[0])
        data["string2"].append(case[2])
        data["number1"].append(case[1])
        data["number2"].append(case[3])
```

The result is a dictionary you may use as dataframe itself or directly convert it to a data structure of your liking (numpy, pandas..)

```
{'string1': ['ATTCGGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTA', 'GCAAGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTGA', 'GTAAGATCTAATGACGGACGCTCCA', 'GGCTATTAAGGGGTCGGACGCTCGC', 'GTAACTAAACTTTAACGGACGCTCC'],
 'number1': [423575, 423600, 423625, 423650, 423675],
 'string2': ['user_name', 'user_name2', 'user_name3', 'user_name4', 'user_name5'],
 'number2': [29708252, 3276541, 923408271, 923408271, 653053443]}
```

Note, that this script will only take well-formed blocks of four lines. All other entries are discarded. If this is not what you want, you'd need to formulate an else-statement after `if len(case)==4:`.

Answer (score 2):

With `grep` and `paste`:

```
<infile grep -v -e SEQUENCE -e END | paste - - - -
```

Output:

```
ATTCGGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTA   423575  user_name   029708252
GCAAGTCTAATGACGGACGCTCTGA   423600  user_name2  03276541
GTAAGATCTAATGACGGACGCTCCA   423625  user_name3  00923408271
GGCTATTAAGGGGTCGGACGCTCGC   423650  user_name4  00923408271
GTAACTAAACTTTAACGGACGCTCC   423675  user_name5  0653053443
```

Comment: interesting and simple answer, didn't know the existence of *paste* , UV